# NSProxy incompatible pointer types

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers, nsproxy

I have an `NSProxy` subclass called `EBManagedObject` and an `NSObject` subclass called `EBObject`. `EBManagedObject` is initialized with a guid that is used to retrieve an `EBObject` from `EBObjectRepository`. `EBManagedObject` will forward any message sent to it to its `EBObject`, except for some restricted messages, in which case it will throw an exception. So wherever you can use an `EBObject` you can use an `EBManagedObject`. My problem is that Xcode doesn't understand this and gives me an incompatible pointer types warning when trying to do the following:

```
EBObject *object = [[EBManagedObject alloc] initWithGuid:guid];
```

It's simple enough to fix:

```
EBObject *object = (EBObject *)[[EBManagedObject alloc] initWithGuid:guid];
```

But I am wondering if there is any way to make Xcode consider `EBObject` and `EBManagedObject` compatible pointer types?

I know I could create a protocol that both of them implement and do something like:

```
id<EBObject> object = [[EBManagedObject alloc] initWithGuid:guid];
```

But I have good reasons not to do that.

By the way, all the class names are made up. My actual scenario is more complex, so I made a simplified example to explain my problem.

Comment: You said that `EBManagedObject` was subclassed from `NSProxy`, not `EBObject`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. There is no inheritance between these two objects.